# Unicorn Meta Zoo #7: Interview with Nicolas

Tags: discussion, podcast, unicorn-meta-zoo

Welcome to the Unicorn Meta Zoo, a podcast by members of the Stack
Exchange Community Management Team. If you want to avoid spoilers, jump
[straight to the audio](https://dts.podtrac.com/redirect.mp3/unicorn-meta-zoo.github.io/episodes/nicolas.mp3).

#### Participants

[image: Nicolas Chabanovsky]
[image: Jon Ericson]

Back in May, I interviewed [Nicolas Chabanovsky](https://stackoverflow.blog/2015/06/11/welcome-nicolas-chabanovsky-and-stack-overflow-in-russian/) 
while we both were in NYC for a meetup. Nicolas has been instrumental in helping out international Stack Overflow sites to be among [the most active on the network](https://stackexchange.com/sites#questionsperday).

#### Links

- [Stack Overflow на русском](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/)
- [Stack Overflow en español](https://es.stackoverflow.com/)
- [Stack Overflow em Português](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/)
- [スタック・オーバーフロー](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/)
- [Русский язык](https://rus.stackexchange.com/)

#### Meta

Jon Ericson interviewed several community managers at our most recent
meet-up. There were three questions:

1. What, if anything, gets you excited about your job?
2. How did your life experience before Stack Exchange prepare you for
   this role?
3. What is your favorite site?

We're running these interviews for the summer (or winter, if you are
in the southern hemisphere) and we'll be back to the regular format
next episode.

#### What do you think?

[Take a listen](https://dts.podtrac.com/redirect.mp3/unicorn-meta-zoo.github.io/episodes/nicolas.mp3) and respond in the answers below.

Answer (score 43):

A question I expected you to add (to the usual three) that you didn't: does Nicolas read all four of those languages?  Russian yes, but also the others?  If not, how do you overcome the language challenges when working to support those communities?

Comment: Thank you for the question! I use Google Translate in combination with the common sense, but it is not all the time enough. The best example is the Japanese language. Sometimes it is really hard to understand what the author means in Japanese when looking at the translation. If that happens I ask my coworkers or volunteers to help me with the translation. Without volunteers' help our international communities would feel very isolated, that is true even for SOru. A lot fo thanks to them!

Comment: I think @Nicolas has also been very good at creating good links with users on each site, with whom we gather on [The Terminal](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/84778) and we clarify posts when necessary.

Answer (score 2):

I have been thinking about it ever since the time Unicorn Meta Zoo interviews have started; is it okay if we do video interviews instead?

Comment: There are several downsides to video for me: 1) Harder to edit. (My [current process](https://github.com/jericson/edit_podcast.rb) is primitive, but automatic. That wouldn't be acceptable for video.) 2) More stress since we are recording from our homes. (I have family walking behind me while recording sometimes.) 3) Less convenient to consume. (Podcasts are great for driving or while doing repetitive tasks at work.) So I'm not going to say video _won't_ happen, but there are a lot of hurdles to clear before we'd consider it.

Comment: @Jon fair enough!  Thanks.

Comment: No, thanks. Unless something is added that can only be done on video: white boarding, demoing of software / prototypes / web interfaces, presentations with slides, etc.